# Send value to function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have this script for show image preview :**

```
<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt,ids) {
var files = evt.target.files;
var f = files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
return function(e) {
document.getElementById(''+ids).innerHTML = ['<img src="', e.target.result,'" title="', theFile.name, '" width="50"/>'].join('');
};
})(f);

reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
</script>


<input type="file" id="files2" />
<output id="list2"></output>


<script>
document.getElementById('files2').addEventListener('change',handleFileSelect('evt','list2'),false);
</script>


<input type="file" id="files3" />
<output id="list3"></output>

<script>  document.getElementById('files3').addEventListener('change',handleFileSelect('evt','list3'),false);
</script>
```

For do this , with fifferent input files , and show in each case preview image , i need change id of container for show preview of each image in each case , etc

```
function handleFileSelect(evt,ids)
```

**ids use for send this different id for each case :**

```
<input type="file" id="files2" />
    <output id="list2"></output>

<input type="file" id="files3" />
    <output id="list3"></output>
```

For works i need send this **ids** to function from **addEventListener** , but no get works

**Thank´s for the help , regards**

Comment: I can't understand the question. You need to improve the language used here as it's unreadable now.

Comment: I want send id of div to function it´s very easy understand i want get

Comment: Not able to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `addEventListener` must be a function. You're not passing a function, you're calling the function and passing its return value. It should be:

```
document.getElementById('files2').addEventListener('change', function() {
    handleFileSelect('evt','list2');
}, false);
```